# How to define an array of a class in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, class

I have define a class with 2 data fields and get/set methods in PowerShell as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
    [string]$Field1
    [string]$Field2

    MyClass() {}

    MyClass([string]$Field1, [string]$Field2)
    {
      SetField1($Field1)
      SetField2($Field2)
    }

    [string]GetField1()
    {
      return $($this.Field1)     
    }

    [string]GetField2()
    {
      return $($this.Field2)
    }

    [void]SetField1([string]$Field1)
    {
      $this.Field1 = $Field1
    }

    [void]SetField2([string]$Field2)
    {
      $this.Field2 = $Field2
    }
}
```

How do I define an array called MyArray for MyClass so that I can add data to the MyArray object ?

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SomeObjects.Count; ++i) {
    ....
    $MyArray[$i]($Field1, $Field2)
}
```

Comment: You need to change `SetField1($Field1)` to `$this.SetField1($Field1)` and `SetField2($Field2)` to `$this.SetField2($Field2)`.

Comment: Whats the point of your get / set methods in your class when you can do `$instance.Property` and `$instance.Property = 'value'`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an array of type MyClass and expected size, then in a loop create new objects and assign field values.

```
$MyArray = [MyClass[]]::new($SomeObjects.Count)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SomeObjects.Count; $i++) {
  $MyArray[$i]=[MyClass]::new()
  $MyArray[$i].Field1 = $Field1
  $MyArray[$i].Field1 = $Field2
}
```

You could also use `$MyArray[$i]=[MyClass]::new($Field1,$Field2)`, but first fix the class, as using this constructor throws an error (`'SetField1' is not recognized ...`)

Comment: Also, if the size isn't fixed, you can use dynamic collections, such as `$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[MyClass]]::new()`

Comment: I tried $MyArray = [MyClass[]]::new($SomeObjects.Count) or $MyArray = New-Object MyClass[]]($SomeObjects.Count) and both works, but how do I create an array of Myclass without specify the number of elements in the array ?

Comment: It looks like $MyArray = [MyClass[]]::new($SomeObjects.Count) have only initialized the array but did not initialize the class object.